# International Data Encryption Algorithm(IDEA) in C/Python

Tags: python, c, encryption, mcrypt

I wish to implement IDEA algorithm in one of my programs for encryption purposes. I thought of implementing it at first but quickly gave up the idea as it seemed too complex for me to implement. I searched over the net for any library implementation of the same and stuck upon mcrypt. But idea is a non-free package of mcrypt as it says [here](http://je.je/cgi-bin/man/man2html?libmcrypt+3). Is there any way I can add IDEA to mcrypt? Or is there any library which provides this encryption functionality in C/Python?

Comment: [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Data_Encryption_Algorithm) the patent has expired `The last patents expired in 2012 and IDEA is now patent-free and thus free to use.` I was not able to find IDEA implementations in Python yet. Is there a publicly, free available implementation in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**2015 Update:**
The last of the IDEA patents apparently expired in 2012.  However, as a 64-bit block size cipher its design is quite outdated, so it should not be considered for new system designs.

---

The "non-free" description of IDEA is because the cipher is patent-encumbered in Europe, the US and Japan.

You can still download and compile the mcrypt IDEA module, or compile OpenSSL with the IDEA cipher enabled.  It is up to you to ensure that you are not infringing the patent(s).  The patent owners, Ascom Systec Ltd., have made it available royalty-free for certain applications:

> The IDEA algorithm is patented by
>   Ascom Systec Ltd. of CH-5506
>   Maegenwil,   Switzerland, who allow it
>   to be used on a royalty-free basis for
>   certain   non-profit applications. 
>   Commercial users must obtain a license
>   from the   company in order to use
>   IDEA.  IDEA may be used on a
>   royalty-free basis under   the
>   following conditions:
>
> Free use for private purposes:
>
> The free use of software containing
>   the algorithm is strictly limited to
>   non   revenue generating data transfer
>   between private individuals, ie not
>   serving   commercial purposes. 
>   Requests by freeware developers to
>   obtain a   royalty-free license to
>   spread an application program
>   containing the   algorithm for
>   non-commercial purposes must be
>   directed to Ascom.
>
> Special offer for shareware
>   developers:
>
> There is a special waiver for
>   shareware developers.  Such waiver
>   eliminates   the upfront fees as well
>   as royalties for the first US$10,000
>   gross sales of   a product containing
>   the algorithm if and only if:
>
> 1. The product is being sold for a minimum of US$10 and a maximum of
>      US$50.
> 2. The source code for the shareware is available to the public.
>
>    Special conditions for research
>      projects:
>
>    The use of the algorithm in research
>      projects is free provided that it
>      serves   the purpose of such project
>      and within the project duration.  Any
>      use of the   algorithm after the
>      termination of a project including
>      activities resulting   from a project
>      and for purposes not directly related
>      to the project requires   a license.
>
>    Ascom Tech requires the following
>      notice to be included for freeware
>      products:
>
>    This software product contains the
>      IDEA algorithm as described and
>      claimed in   US patent 5,214,703, EPO
>      patent 0482154 (covering Austria,
>      France, Germany,   Italy, the
>      Netherlands, Spain, Sweden,
>      Switzerland, and the UK), and Japanese
>      patent application 508119/1991,
>      "Device for the conversion of a
>      digital block   and use of same"
>      (hereinafter referred to as "the
>      algorithm").  Any use of   the
>      algorithm for commercial purposes is
>      thus subject to a license from Ascom
>      Systec Ltd. of CH-5506 Maegenwil
>      (Switzerland), being the patentee and
>      sole   owner of all rights, including
>      the trademark IDEA.
>
>    Commercial purposes shall mean any
>      revenue generating purpose including
>      but   not limited to:
>
>    i) Using the algorithm for company
>      internal purposes (subject to a site
>       license).
>
>    ii) Incorporating the algorithm into
>      any software and distributing such
>        software and/or providing services relating thereto to others
>      (subject to
>        a product license).
>
>    iii) Using a product containing the
>      algorithm not covered by an IDEA
>      license
>         (subject to an end user license).
>
>    All such end user license agreements
>      are available exclusively from Ascom
>      Systec Ltd and may be requested via
>      the WWW at http://www.ascom.ch/systec
>      or   by email to idea@ascom.ch.
>
>    Use other than for commercial
>      purposes is strictly limited to
>      non-revenue   generating data transfer
>      between private individuals.  The use
>      by government   agencies, non-profit
>      organizations, etc is considered as
>      use for commercial   purposes but may
>      be subject to special conditions.  Any
>      misuse will be   prosecuted.

Comment: The problem is that it isn't distributed by mcrypt at all anymore, unlike some other patented algos: They removed it from the repo almost ten years ago. The site I posted above was the only one I found with a copy of it still.

Comment: @SilverbackNet: Well, it's definitely still distributed with OpenSSL, so you could use that library instead (the C interface is the functions in `<openssl/idea.h>`).

Comment: I installed openssl and while listing cipher commands it doesn't show idea. While configuring the idea files are configured, but running make all says nothing to make in idea folder.

Comment: @primalpop: Then you've done something wrong - when I download openssl-1.0.0 source, run a plain `./config ; make`, I get IDEA built fine (running `test/ideatest` works, for example).

Comment: You may change your answer or add a header showing [the patent has expired](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Data_Encryption_Algorithm): `The last patents expired in 2012 and IDEA is now patent-free and thus free to use.`

Answer (score 2):

You can get hold of the idea module from [a web site](http://www.ottolander.nl/opensource/mcrypt/mcrypt.html), drop the idea.c and related files in and you should be able to rebuild libmcrypt (and mcrypt if you use it). You can also use the GPG version, or build a separate library yourself, but neither is as simple.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu and the site lists only .rpm packages. Any way around this problem?

Comment: There are no packages out there with it included, and he RPMs are very out-of-date anyway. You have to compile from source, by merging a few .c files from libmcrypt-idea-0.9.tar.bz2 with the current mcrypt source tree. If you need a pre-compiled one you should use OpenSSL.

Comment: I was trying to use openssl but it doesn't include idea module as well.